# Can Rust attributes be used for something like mapping URL routes to functions?

Tags: syntax, attributes, rust

I'd like to know whether or not it is possible to to do something like the following with Rust:

```
#Get(url="api/action")
void action(string[] params) {}
```

To create a REST API, this would be pretty nice syntax sugar. I know that I can create custom attributes for the compiler, but I'm not sure how to best approach this.

For example every method declared with that `Get` attribute could be registered in a global object to register the routes without writing a single line of code.

Can Rust attributes be used for something like this? And if yes, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Yes, it's likely to be possible, but only in unstable Rust as compiler plugins (which allow creating properties) are unstable. Besides that, *global* state is highly discouraged in most programming, especially Rust. Beyond that, it sounds like you are asking to have the code for this solution written for you. I'd recommend checking out [iron/router](https://github.com/iron/router) for a less-invasive solution that works today.

Comment: I'm currently researching different languages fit for doing such things in general. Rust is one of them. I want to do it on my own, I just need to know what's the best approach to do it.
The global object was just as an example.